# How order a JSON alphabetically in javascript, like this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I can ordering a-z using the .sort() method in javascript, but I would get a JSON like this: (With a "A-Z" index containing the result)

```
data: {
      "A": [
        {
          "name": "Anh Tuan Nguyen",
          "age": 28
        },
        {
          "name": "An Nguyen",
          "age": 20
        },
      ],
      "Z": [
        {
          "name": "Zue Dang",
          "age": 22
        },
        {
          "name": "Zoom Jane",
          "age": 30
        },
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to group it based on the first letter in their name?

Comment: Hello @Marco. Nice to have you around. In order to get good answers to your question, there is a little work on your side to do. Please provide  us some code that shows what you have tried so far.

Comment: You might want to post your source array as the kind folks who are answering are assuming it’s an object similar to your desired result.

Comment: Yes! I want to group it based on the first letter in their name

Comment: You need to clarify what your source data is.  “a JSON” isn’t a thing, its either going to be an array or an object.

Comment: It`s an Array!! Sorry for don`t specify. I only want group by a object property in my array after order alphabetically all the array. Sorry if don´t provide a source code, I can´t how start with it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
Exist a JavaScript library that make It possible: Lodash Utilities (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4). Contain methods for .sort() JSON (no Arrays) and a method to obtain the JSON for I asked in this question. I only did this:

```
//First, order my JSON alphabetically with _.sortBy method (I can even order by a nested property in my JSON)    
var order = _.sortBy(require('./names'), function (el) { return el.name });

//Second, I group my order result by the first letter of my property 'name' in my JSON
var list = _.groupBy(order, (b) => b.name[0].toUpperCase());
```

This is my input:

```
[
  {"name":"Mark"},
  {"name":"Jul"},
  {"name":"Alicia"},
]
```

This is my output:

```
[
 "A": [
    {
      "name": "Alicia"
    }
  ],
  "J": [
    {
      "name": "Jul"
    },
  ],
  "M": [
    {
      "name": "Mark"
    },
  ]
```

I hope this help to somebody!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to sort a JSON data structure, however, we can do it by using the following process:

1. Get your `data` keys with `Object.keys(myResults.data)`
2. Sort you keys
3. Create a reduce function to transform your ordered keys into an ordered object

The snippet is here, I hope it helps:

```js
var myResults = {
  data: {
    C: [
      {
        "name": "Kevin Doe",
        "age": 22
      }
    ],
    A: [
      {
        "name": "Alex Doe",
        "age": 31,
      }
    ],
    B: [
        {
          "name": "Boris Doe",
          "age": 22
        },
        {
          "name": "Birdo Doe",
          "age": 30
        },
     ]
  }
};

var originalData = myResults.data;

// 1. get the keys
var dataKeys = Object.keys(originalData);

// 2. sort the keys
var sortedKeys = dataKeys.sort();

// 3. create the object again
var orderedData = sortedKeys.reduce(function(result, key) {
  return Object.assign(
    {},
    result,
    { [key]: myResults.data[key] }
  );
}, {});

document.getElementById('original').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(originalData);
document.getElementById('sorted').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(orderedData);
```

```css
h3 {
  margin: 0;
}

code {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

```html
<h3>Original Data</h3>
<code id="original"></code>

<h3>Ordered Data</h3>
<code id="sorted"></code>
```

Comment: This works for me! Thanks!!

Comment: Sure, would you mind marking the answer as correct? :) @MarcoDuarte

Answer (score 1):

```
var names = [{name:"a1"},{name:"a2"},{name:"b1"},{name:"b2"}.....];
var data = {};
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
var n = names[i].name.subStr(0,1);
if (data[n] == null)
   data[n] = [];
   data[n].push(names[i]);
                    }
```

Comment: This is probably right assuming source data is an array.

Comment: if its an object and not array, you can change "for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++)" to "(for var i in names)"

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript objects are not ordered. If you want to iterate over an object's properties, you can sort the keys and then retrieve your values:

```js
const result = {
  data: {
    Z: [],
    F: [],
    A: [],
    D: []
  }
};

Object
  .keys(result.data)
  .sort()
  .map(key => console.log(key, result.data[key]));
```